# Adding workflow exemption criteria

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, email

I have a working email notification set up for new list items however I would like to build in an exemption criteria.

I have a number of users adding items that I need to track but I also add quite a few myself. I would like to stop sharepoint emailing me (a specific user) when 'I' add a new item but continue to email me when it is added by all other users.

I am using Sharepoint Online with Designer 2013

Thank you

Scott

Comment: did below worked ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I was not able to work it into the existing workflow so am just putting up witht the extra emails but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Below flow can be used in workflow to do this...

```
Start Workflow
        Set Variable ExemptedUserEmail = "Email id of user which you wanted to exempt"

         Set  Variable CreatedByUserEmail - Set email id of people who created this item.


       If(ExemptedUserEmail  != CreatedByUserEmail )
                Action - Set email to user

       Else
                Action - do nothing
```

End workflow